# MS Teams on Windows 10 - microphone not working when using RDP to laptop

Tags: windows-10, audio, microsoft-teams

I'm using remote desktop to go from my desktop to work laptop, but when I do this the microphone built into my work webcam disappears as an option and therefore no-one can hear me.

If I work directly on the laptop, MS Teams shows me this option which works fine:

[Before Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWKVc.png)

But, when I remote from the desktop into the laptop, this screen changes and I don't get any options in the microphone drop down:

[During a Remote Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2K6h.png)

The options I have set in the remote desktop for audio are:

[Remote desktop audio settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK6xM.png)

I have tried plugging the work webcam into my desktop and using remote audio for both playback and recording, and this does work but produces too much echo on the call for others (presumably as both the desktop and laptop are in the same room albeit on different desks). I also can't use MS Teams on my desktop due to work policies, and I'm trying to avoid having to go between the desks so remote desktop would be ideal if I can get this microphone working.

Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: It is not advised to try and get this to work. There will be huge delays, stutter and overhead for the server, which is why it does not work by default. It is much better to use your laptop locally for this. You can still share your screen and go to the remote desktop that way, so you don't lose any functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why would there be huge delays/stutter/overhead and what server do you mean? The laptop and desktop and both in the same room, and I'd be using the same webcam for audio and video but would just be able to use my desktop monitors to see the teams call that's running on the laptop.